# Return the proper json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ReturnJson()
    {
        List<Tuple<string, int>> list = new List<Tuple<string,int>>();
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Feb 2 to Feb 6", 1));
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Feb 7 to Feb 15", 10));
        list.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Feb 16 to Feb 24", 4));

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

it returns the following string:

```
[{"Item1":"Feb 2 to Feb 6","Item2":1},{"Item1":"Feb 7 to Feb 15","Item2":10},{"Item1":"Feb 16 to Feb 24","Item2":4}]
```

on my View I should get this in format (javascript)

```
var data = [["Jan 26 to Jun 30", 8], ["Feb 2 to Feb 6", 15], ["Feb 9 to Feb 13", 16], ["Feb 16 to Feb 20", 7], ["Feb 23 to Feb 27", 16], ["Mar 2 to Mar 6", 8], ["Mar 9 to Mar 13", 4], ["Mar 16 to Mar 20", 15]];
```

How to convert first string to second on server or client side?
Thanks

Comment: Tuples aren't arrays.  It looks like you want a list of lists (or arrays), not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tuple to list:

```
List<List<object>> list = new List<List<object>>();
list.Add(new List<object> {"Feb 2 to Feb 6", 1});
list.Add(new List<object> {"Feb 7 to Feb 15", 10});
list.Add(new List<object> {"Feb 16 to Feb 24", 4});

return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```